# Multiply Tensors with different ranks

Tags: tensorflow, algebra, tensor

I would like to multiply two tensors with different ranks, e.g.

```
tensor A -> (i x j x k x l)
tensor B -> (l x m)
```

to get another tensor with this dimensions.

```
tensor C -> (i x j x k x m) = (i x j x k x l)*(l x m)
```

In tensorflow I have to reshape all the time to get the output as

```
(A.reshape(-1,l)*B).reshape(i,j,k,m)
```

Any other operation that does it directly?

Comment: Are you trying to multiple these tensors elementwise, or perform a (batch) matrix multiplication?

Comment: It is a matrix multiplication like this (i x j x k x l)*(l x m) = (i x j x k x m). Possibly, it is a batch matrix multiplication.

Comment: But then you need to use `tf.matmul` and not `*`

Comment: `tf.matmul` gives rank error (Tensorflow 1.4). `np.matmul` seems to work as expected.

Comment: use tf.tensordot: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969305

Answer (score 3):

You need [tf.tensordot](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot). Reshaping before real multiplication is not necessary. If you want to contract tensor A and B along the A's last dimension and the B's first dimension, you can multiply tensor A and tensor B in this way:

```
tf.tensordot(A, B, axes=[[3], [0]])
```