# Broadcasting np.dot vs tf.matmul for tensor-matrix multiplication (Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 error)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, tensor

Let's say I have the following tensors:

```
X = np.zeros((3,201, 340))
Y = np.zeros((340, 28))
```

Making a dot product of X, Y is successful with numpy, and yields a tensor of shape (3, 201, 28).
However with tensorflow I get the following error: `Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 error ...`

minimal code example:

```
X = np.zeros((3,201, 340))
Y = np.zeros((340, 28))
print(np.dot(X,Y).shape) # successful (3, 201, 28)
tf.matmul(X, Y) # errornous
```

Any idea how to achieve the same result with tensorflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since, you are working with `tensors`, it would be better (for performance) to use `tensordot` there than `np.dot`. NumPy allows it (numpy.dot) to work on `tensors` through lowered performance and it seems `tensorflow` simply doesn't allow it.

So, for NumPy, we would use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) -

```
np.tensordot(X, Y, axes=((2,),(0,)))
```

For `tensorflow`, it would be with [`tf.tensordot`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/tensordot) -

```
tf.tensordot(X, Y, axes=((2,),(0,)))
```

[Related post to understand `tensordot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870228/).

Comment: Although your answer probably works (I haven't tested), to create a tuple of a single element, you should do `(element,)`. `(element)` is just the same as `element`, i.e. it doesn't create a tuple.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi `tensordot` expects a tuple of two tuples as the axes param. That's what we are feeding here.

Comment: That's exactly the point. `((2),(0))` is equivalent to `(2, 0)`, because the inner parantheses are used for grouping rather than creating a tuple. To create a tuple of two tuples do `((2,),(0,))`.

Comment: @HameerAbbasi Ah I guess it works just as well with a tuple of scalars as well for this special one axis reduction case.

Comment: OP here: Actually, to make it work I've had to use `((2,),(0,))`

Comment: @yuval Ah okay. Edited post. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow doesn't allow for multiplication of matrices with different ranks as numpy does.

To cope with this, you can reshape the matrix. This essentially casts a matrix of, 
 say, rank 3 to one with rank 2 by "stacking the matrices" one on top of the other.

You can use this:
`tf.reshape(tf.matmul(tf.reshape(Aijk,[i*j,k]),Bkl),[i,j,l])`

where i, j and k are the dimensions of matrix one and k and l are the dimensions of matrix 2.

Taken from [here](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/discuss/RY-s6MEZRj8).