# Any suggestions for multiplying a tensor (along an arbitrary axis) with a matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, matrix-multiplication, tensor

I have a tensor of rank N and bond dimension d with shape `T=(d,...,d)`.
I would like to multiply with a matrix `M=(D,d)` where D is not the same as d.
The resulting tensor should have shape `(d,...,d,D,d,...,d)`.

While I can do this to get eg `(d,...,d,D,d,d)` tensor:

```
np.einsum('ij, ...jkl->...ikl', M,T)
```

The tensor can be of quite a large rank and I need to do this several times. Therefore I want to avoid writing out each particular case as I did above as it would be impractical.

Can anyone suggest a better/more general/alternative way to do this? I would really appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem.
What you want is mutiply two tensors on specific dimensions and obtain a new tensor with a specific shape.

I tried different approaches and eventually came up with a composition of `numpy.tensordot` and `numpy.rollaxis`.

The former allows the tensor product between specified axes. The latter rotates the tensor to get the expected shape.

It was an interesting question, thanks. I hope I got this right, let me know.

```
import numpy as np
d=4
N=5
D=7
T = np.random.randint(0,9, (d,)*N)
M = np.random.randint(0,9, (D,d))

r = np.einsum('ij, ...jkl->...ikl', M,T)

i = 1
j = -3 

v = np.tensordot(M,T,axes=[[i],[j]])
v = np.rollaxis(v,0,j)

assert((v==r).all())
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! With little change it becomes exactly what I was looking for.

`i = 1`
`j = -2`
`v = np.tensordot(M,T,axes=[[i],[j-1]])`
`v = np.rollaxis(v,0,j)`

Answer (score 0):

A matrix is similar (not equal) to a tensor of rank 2 https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20437/are-matrices-and-second-rank-tensors-the-same-thing , [Multiply Tensors with different ranks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267240/multiply-tensors-with-different-ranks) )

In `scikit-tensor` are tensor-matrix operations ( https://pypi.org/project/scikit-tensor/ )

> scikit-tensor is a Python module for multilinear algebra and tensor
> factorizations. Currently, scikit-tensor supports basic tensor
> operations such as folding/unfolding, **tensor-matrix** and tensor-vector
> products as well as the following tensor factorizations
>
> ```
> Canonical / Parafac Decomposition
> Tucker Decomposition
> RESCAL
> DEDICOM
> INDSCAL
> ```
>
> Moreover, all operations support dense and tensors.

source : https://github.com/mnick/scikit-tensor

Tensor contraction :

https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/252473/converting-between-matrix-multiplication-and-tensor-contraction

Comment: Please forgive my imprecise language. This was just a computational problem; for my purposes it relates to the shape of the portion of the data I want to store and manipulate.